# Python: print text weird sentence

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having a problem with my code here:

```
f=open("Test.txt","r")
print(f)
```

The word in Test.txt is "false",I want to print "false"in my program but it shows:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='Test.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp950'>
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4):

[`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) only gives you a file object. Here is the documentation:

> Open file and return a corresponding **file object**. If the file cannot be opened, an OSError is raised.

What you want is to read the file, preferably using a [context manager (`with`)](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm):

```
with open('Test.txt') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 4):

You are printing handler to file. To get contents you need to use [`read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) method. You can also use [context manager](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/) ([docs about `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)) so your code would look like this:

```
with open("Test.txt", "r") as my_file:
    print(my_file.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
f=open("Test.txt","r").read()
print(f)
```

The .read() helps to read the data present in that file as without it variable 'f' is just an unread file object.